# PHP-JWT creates incorrect token for Firebase 3

Tags: php, firebase, jwt

I had authentication using JWT working fine in Firebase 2 but since moving to Firebase 3 I cannot get it to work. I am thinking this is due to the token-generator library not generating the correct JWT. Can anyone see where the problem is please?

JS Code:

```
// set Firebase from config
var config = {
        apiKey: 'api_key',
        authDomain: 'domain',
        databaseURL: 'database_url',
        storageBucket: 'storage_bucket',
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.database.enableLogging(true);

var ref = firebase.database();

firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(jwt).catch(function(error) {

if (error) {

    console.log("Authentication Failed!", error.code + ' ' + error.message);

} else {  
...
}
```

PHP Code:

Uses: firebase-php , php-jwt and token-generator

```
$now_seconds = time();
$payload = array(
                'iss' => FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
                'sub' => FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
                'aud' => 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit',
                'iat' => $now_seconds,
                'exp' => $now_seconds+(60*60),  // Maximum expiration time is one hour
                'uid' => $uid
);
return JWT::encode($payload, FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY, 'HS256');
```

Debug:

```
p:0: Browser went online.  
firebase.js:354 p:0: Auth token refreshed  
firebase.js:354 p:0: Making a connection attempt  
firebase.js:354 getToken() completed. Creating connection.
firebase.js:354 c:0:0: Connection created  
firebase.js:354 c:0:0:0 Websocket connecting to wss://my-app.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=my-app  
my-page:1041 POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken?key=my-key 400 ()
firebase.js:354 c:0:0:0 Websocket connected.  
firebase.js:354 c:0:0: Realtime connection established.  
firebase.js:354 p:0: connection ready  
firebase.js:354 p:0: reportStats {"c":{"sdk.js.3-0-0":1}}  
firebase.js:354 p:0: {"r":1,"a":"s","b":{"c":{"sdk.js.3-0-0":1}}}  
firebase.js:354 p:0: from server: {"r":1,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}  
about:blank:1 Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cloudconsole&osid=1&passiv…=http%3A%2F%2Flocal.domain.com%3ALOCALPORTNUMBER&pfname=&rpctoken=RPCTOKENNUMBER' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
firebase.js:354 c:0:0: sending ping on primary.  
firebase.js:354 c:0:0: got pong on primary.  
firebase.js:354 c:0:0: Primary connection is healthy.
```

Comment: Also posted here, with some additional details and resolutions. https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/firebase-talk/cbE5TAJF9fM/MO8N-3j7FwAJ